# Express/Nodejs - Why does the ejs renderFile function need to be included in my engine setup If i am only using plain html and no ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, mean

here is the code snippet for my view engine setup

```
//view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

I am only using plain html, why does ejs need to be included at all? Is there no basic engine setup for html? My code work fine by the way, Im just trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: How are you planning on passing data to your views using vanilla HTML?  If you are just serving static files, Express isn't necessary.

Comment: I am creating a simple MEAN app to gain better understanding of the stack. I am new to express and the MEAN stack as a whole. I just know that I am not using any embedded javascript. I Just don't understand why something like 'app.engine("html");' wouldnt work if i replaced the 2nd line with it.

Comment: Those lines are only really required if you plan on embedding pieces of data into HTML and sending that.  You can serve static files with `express.static()` only and call it a day technically.